# execute output parameter sql server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, join, parameters

I have three parameters `@code` is anyone element of `table1.column1`, `@date` is the date of the element `table2.column2` and `@total` would be an output parameter that shows the times that appear the element `table2.column2`.

I would want to perform a procedure that show me the inner join between `table1.column1` and `table2.column1` with the `date_column`; only dates before parameter introduced `@date`.

And also return the select sum of rows in `@total`

```
create procedure pro1
    @code int, 
    @date datetime, 
    @total smallint OUTPUT
as
    select 
       table1.column1, table2.date_column
    from 
       table1 
    inner join 
       table2 on table1.column1 = table2.column2
    where 
       table1.column1 = @code 
       and table2.date_column = @date 
       and @date <= table2.date_column
```

Comment: You say "sum of rows" - can you clarify? Do you mean "sum of (some column)" or "count of rows"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading you correctly, `@total` is just the number of rows returned. If that is indeed the case, then you can eliminate the need for repeating the query (plus having to handle concurrency issues, such as the data being modified in between the queries):

```
create procedure pro1
(
    @code int, @date datetime, @total smallint OUTPUT
)
as
begin
select
    table1.column1,
    table2.date_column
from
    table1
    inner join
    table2 on table1.column1 = table2.column2
where
    table1.column1 = @code
    and
    table2.date_column = @date
    and
    @date <= table2.date_column;

set @total = @@rowcount;
end
```

Comment: Thank you!!, is useful to use the rowcount function.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, in a select statement you cannot Assign values to a variable and also return data, therefore you will need to execute this query twice, once to return the data you are expecting back and once to assign value to the `@Total` parameter.

```
create procedure pro1
  @code int
 ,@date datetime
 ,@total int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
select table1.column1
    , table2.date_column
from table1 
inner join table2  on table1.column1 = table2.column2
where table1.column1 = @code 
  and CAST(table2.date_column AS DATE) = @date 
  and table2.date_column <= @date

select @total = SUM(table1.column1)
from table1 
inner join table2  on table1.column1 = table2.column2
where table1.column1 = @code 
  and CAST(table2.date_column AS DATE) = @date 
  and table2.date_column <= @date  

END
```

Comment: thank you for your help, only shows me the date parameter instead of the previous dates.